# Does embedded onedrive media pose a risk to the owner of the onedrive account?

Tags: web-application, microsoft-onedrive

I have a personal website that acts as a portfolio for my engineering projects. There are images of my projects that i'd like to have on the site. Would it be a bad idea to embed these from a onedrive account? In other words, do embedded images hosted on a onedrive account make that account more vulnerable to a breach? Lets assume you have 'edits' turned off so the user cannot make any changes to the file and they are view-only.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see an added risk to your OneDrive account apart from the potential disclosure of your account name, if users can view the owner of these files. When using a good password and enabling two-factor authentication, this should not pose a serious risk.

From the security perspective on your website, however, it would be better if the images were hosted on the site itself. This way, you can better restrict from which sources images can be included using the Content-Security-Policy header.

Comment: At first glance, there does not seem to be any mention of the onedrive user name in the URL for embedded onedrive files. I suppose this is another question in itself.. How could someone get the user name from a one drive image?